# How to hide one element with position absolute?

Tags: css

I have a responsive navbar with an absolute position, but I also have an element with absolute position in home page. How I can overlay the first element??[image]

Comment: what have you tried ? where is the code ?

Comment: I tried to use Z-index.  Its in separate files, CSS navbar and CSS footer linked by EJS layouts

Comment: show the code that you tried

Comment: This code so large. But, the property Z-index does not work, because that in separete files. are you have a alternative for line with circle in center, that not use position absolute?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The CSS [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property allows you to specify the layering order of different elements (which appear on top of each other).

**Based on follow up comments:**

Because you are using a transform on the element you would like to position below the other, use a transform on the other element as well (ex: `transform: translateX(0px);`).
Transforms move elements to a separate [stacking-context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) (generally above others).

Comment: I tried to use Z-index.  Its in separate files, CSS navbar and CSS footer linked by EJS layouts

Comment: Can you provide more information? Please provide enough information to understand what css is currently responsible for positioning these elements.

Comment: .nav-list {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8vh;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 92vh;
        background-color: white;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    }. This code is responsable to responsive navbar. Its activate by javascript. Zindex does not work here

Comment: Try adding a transform to the element you would like to position above it. (ex: `transform: translateX(0px);`). Spatial transforms move elements to a separate render mode. (generally above others)